# GLSL: Get world space direction vector from camera to fragment

Tags: 3d, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

In a 3D post-processing shader I need to find the dot product between a light source (known in world space) and the "camera ray" at a specific fragment. In the shader, I don't have any depth information, as it is just post-processing an already rendered scene. However, I have the projection and view matrix of the original render pass.

As I understand it right, I can calculate the camera direction vector into world space using something like that:

```glsl
vec4 camDirection = inverse(projectionViewMatrix) * vec4(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
camDirection.xyz /= camDirection.w;
```

However, how since I have a perspective projection, the direction vector is different for every fragment. I was trying to use the screen-space coordinate as base for a vector which I then unproject. I think it would make sense to do something like this:

```glsl
vec4 fragDirection = inverse(projectionViewMatrix)* vec4(screenSpace.xy * fov, 1.0, 1.0);
fragDirection.xyz /= fragDirection.w;
```

But what do I use as Z-coordinate for this vector? What is the best practice to calculate the fragments direction from the camera?

**Edit:** The direction vector from the camera should be normalized. The geometry it would hit should not matter. It will be used to determine the strongness of a godray effect at a specific fragment.

[image: Sketch]

Comment: Side note: You need to multiply _matrix * vector_ rather than _vector * matrix_: `inverse(projectionViewMatrix) * vec4(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);`

Comment: You can write this dot product to alpha channel during render pass that generates an image for PP. Multiplying by inverse projection matrix brings the result only if you have depth.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, corrected it!

Comment: @Hihikomori But why is that so? The normalized direction vector and the resulting dot product should be independent from how close some unrelated is to the camera, as the screen space coordinates are linear from left to right, and top to bottom. I am really just searching the normalized vector, not the vector to the rendered geometry.

Comment: Multiplying the inverse projection matrix you will get the mesh that will be the plane with z = z_far (or z_near)

Comment: This approach will work only if the depth map is almost flat. You can bind to shader texture from depth attachment of your frame buffer,to get the correct result.

Comment: @Hihikomori I added a sketch to clarify what I am trying to do. For what I am trying to do, the depth should be constant for every fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226302/discussion-between-bastian-born-and-hihikomori).